# How to join table in sqlite with two different conditions and to get one result row

Tags: mysql, sqlite

I have table "locations" with locations... e.g.

```
location_id location_name
=========================
1           Location A
2           Location B
3           Location C
```

And table "movements" where I record moving something from location A to location B for specified item:

```
id  item_id loc1_id loc2_id
===========================
1   1       1       3
2   2       2       1
```

I need to get in one result row movement for specified item_id and location names...

I have tried sample, for item_id=1:

```
select `movements`.*,`locations`.`location_name` from `movements`
    inner join `locations` 
    on (`locations`.`location_id`=`movements`.`loc1_id` or `locations`.`location_id`=`movements`.`loc2_id`)
    where `movements`.`item_id`=1;
```

But that returns 2 rows like this:

```
id  item_id loc1_id loc2_id location_name
=========================================
1   1       1       3       Location A
1   1       1       3       Location C
```

Is there any way to get both names with one query and one result row? I'm using SQLite, but I hope MySQL command can help, too.

Comment: You mean something like limit 1? can you add an example of what are you expecting as a result?

Comment: If I limit it, only first row will be displayed... But I need both results

Comment: well.. for result I expect both location names under some aliases to be displayed in row 1... for example:

` id  item_id loc1_id loc2_id location_name1 location_name2
 =========================================
 1   1       1       3       Location A Location C`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you want, (http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/0d70a/1)

```
SELECT 
  b.id,b.item_id,b.loc1_id,b.loc2_id,l1.location_name location_name1,l2.location_name location_name2
FROM
  movements b
INNER JOIN locations l1 ON l1.location_id=b.loc1_id
INNER JOIN locations l2 ON l2.location_id=b.loc2_id
WHERE
  b.item_id=1
```

I tested it on SQLlite and MYSQL

Comment: Thanks a lot, that was I looking for... double joining table with different name. Excellent :)